# Laravel 4 separate config files for packages

Tags: php, laravel-4

My laravel 4 project has multiple environments set up.

The environments setup are: development is called 'development' and production is called 'production'.
In my app/config folder, I have two extra folders. One for each name of the environment.

See screenshot:

[image]

Inside these folders I have separate config files for database.php and app.php.
These are working as expected. Laravel uses my local database configuration when running locally and production when running live.

Now, I've added a new package which requires a config file. This resides in `/app/config/packages/greggilbert/config.php`.

I need to be able to set different config files the same way I do for the database. So, I assumed creating the same file structure in `/development` or `/production` would work, but this does not seem to be the case.

Here is a new screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You have to put the environment-named folder into the package directory: `app/config/packages/<vendor>/<package_name>/<environment>/config.php`

Comment: @Quasdunk That works, if you put this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package-related, environment-specific configuration files have to be placed in the package's directory within a subdirectory named after the environment. So in your case this would be

```
app
   - config
      - packages
         - greggilbert
            - recaptcha
               - development
                  - config.php
               - production
                  - config.php
```

But it can get really ugly and cumbersome in some cases. This can be solved in a (in my opinion) cleaner and more elegant way through [enviroment files](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration) in your application root directory:

**/.env.development.php**

```
<?php
return [

    // any configuration settings for your local environment

    'RECAPTCHA_TEMPLATE' => 'customCaptcha',
    'RECAPTCHA_LANGUAGE' => 'en',

];
```

That way, you could leave the package directory as it is:

```
app
   - config
      - packages
         - greggilbert
            - recaptcha
               - config.php
```

Laravel will load the environment file according to the environment and make the environment variables globally available through `getenv()`. So now you could just grab the specified template for the current environment with `getenv('RECAPTCHA_TEMPLATE')` from the config.php.